# GridView HeaderTemplate Lost DataContext

Tags: wpf, gridview

I have a gridview with HeaderTemplate, I put a button on the header, and have a command attached to it, my ViewModel never gets called.
How do I trace back my ViewModel, seems like it gets "lost".

any ideas ?

Comment: Provide more information with code snippets, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using this:

```
RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,  AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}
```

will bring me back to my `DataContext`.

Answer (score 0):

Column HeaderTemplate  is a generated control part of the DataGrid and does not have direct VisualTree access to the DataGrid's DataContext, so you have to add RelativeSource AncestorType and explicitly refer to the property via the DataContext

```
"{Binding DataContext.AllSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" />
```

or you can also write this to you top element in template

```
 DataContext="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"
```